# How to match two queries of postgres in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have two queries and I want to match the rows of those two queries. That is I want to execute the same number of rows in both the queries. Below code executes the number of dates of the present month and score I have to change it manually every day which is not possible

```
cursor.execute("select TO_CHAR(i :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date),  current_date, '1 day'::interval) i  ")
            # data = cursor.fetchone()
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            labels6 = list()
            i = 0
            for row in rows:
                labels6.append(row[i])
```

Above is the code which executes dates of the current month

```
cursor.execute("select score*100 from daily_stats1 where  user_id=102")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            # Convert query to objects of key-value pairs
            presentmonth1 = list()
            i = 0
            for row in rows[:28]:
                presentmonth1.append(row[i])
```

Above is the code which executes present month score.'28' is given manually I have to change it every day which is not possible.so I want a solution where the date rows match with the score rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the excess indentation in your code is a mistake.
If that is the case, I think this will solve your problem:

```
cursor.execute("select TO_CHAR(i :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from "
               "generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date),  current_date, '1 day'::interval) i  ")
labels6 = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("select score*100 from daily_stats1 where  user_id=102")
presentmonth1 = cursor.fetchall()[:len(labels6)]
```

I removed some unneeded code, but the result should be correct.

Comment: The outstanding solution, Thank you.@cco